# Any documentation on Core Audio's public utility classes?

Tags: core-audio

I've recently begun learning a lot about core audio, and I'm just not understanding what the public utility classes are and how to use them

Answer (score 0):

several Apple sample projects use these, search for :  aurioTouch2 or ConvertFile

these "CoreAudio Utility Classes" include :

```
CADebugMacros.h
CADebugPrintf.h
CAMath.h
CAStreamBasicDescription.cpp
CAStreamBasicDescription.h
CAXException.cpp
CAXException.h
```

Also - there are two very helpful books :

Learning Core Audio by Chris Adamson
Beginning iPhone Games Development published by Apress

in general, these utility classes ease troubleshooting / displaying error msgs

Here is an excerpt from CAStreamBasicDescription.h

```
//=============================================================================
//  CAStreamBasicDescription
//
//  This is a wrapper class for the AudioStreamBasicDescription struct.
//  It adds a number of convenience routines, but otherwise adds nothing
//  to the footprint of the original struct.
//=============================================================================
```

Strictly speaking you do not need these utilities at all.
If you look at the source code projects available online
for the above Learning CA book, Adamson rolls his own consise replacements as needed.